# Is there a way I can delete my friend's waypoint in voxelmap on her server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

Is there a way I can delete my friend's waypoint in voxelmap on her server?
I want to do this troll, but she made a waypoint in the place where I hide and she will just teleport in.

Comment: Do you have access to her computer or here account? Because that would be the only way.

Answer (score 3):

There is no possible way to delete someone's waypoints, unless you have access to their computer or their account. There would be no logical reason as to why this would be possible, therefore, it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Look in controls on her account/computer. Once you find the waypoint button exit the controls and press the waypoint button. Then select the waypoint and you should be able to delete it unless it was changed.